# Compare a bidimensional array to 0 (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I made a loop with a do.while, trying to make the change turns of a game. Now, i want to stop it when any of both array comes to 0, and show the winner. This is for a battleship game.

```
do{ for(int k;toc=1;k++){
    objec1();

     if(toc!=1)
      break;

       }

     for(int k;toc2=1;k++){
        objec2();   
        if(toc2!=1){

            break;
           }

           }

        if(jug1[i][j]==0){ //Here is where the loop must stop
    correct1=true;
 cout<<"\n\tEl The player 2 is the winner\n";
 }
if(jug2[i][j]==0){
    correct1=true;
 cout<<"\n\tPlayer 1 is the winner \n";
 }
 } while(!correct1);
```

In the way I have the code, it does not stop the loop when it Must. Now, I want to check if when an array is full of 0, stop the loop, change the flag and show the winner. The original code is much more extense. Consider that everything is correctly initialized.

Comment: Please sort out the indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think you'll have an easier time with the problem if you fix your formatting, break things up into functions, and use better variable names. Currently it is pretty hard to read and understand.

Secondly, the operation you are talking about is pretty expensive. If you can avoid doing the check this way, that'd be better. For example, maintain a count of non-zero entries, and instead use that as your check condition. Or, if you have information about which battleships are in play, just check when none of them are left.

Anyway, here is a function to find out "when a [two-dimensional] array is full of 0". You can call it from another function.

```
/**
 * array is a 2-d array used by Battleship game
 * i is the outer array size
 * j is the inner array size
 */
bool isAllZeros(int **array, int i, int j) {
    for (int m = 0; m < i; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < j; n++) {
            if (0 != array[i][j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }   
    }   

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a spanish speaker so maybe my way to express myself here is not that good. And sorry, this is my first question. I know I didn't make it in the most correct way. But anyway, your answer just helped me a lot. Thanks, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You dont initialize `k` in your forloops and you dont give them achievable  stop conditions:

```
for(int k;toc=1;k++)
```

The same for the second:

```
for(int k;toc2=1;k++)
```

Comment: The original code is much more extense. Consider that everything is correctly initialized.